# How to put small elements into a big element in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I have a question in Illustrator regarding the picture that I attached:

Is there a command in Illustrator to put a set of elements together into a bigger element considering the angles and rotation of that element? 
(I know there is a way to put all the elements together by composition way and to do a clipping mask but then the icons are cut.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing automated. You would have to manually position, rotate, and size each object.